# Going to a widget on tap Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, indexing, widget

with this code I show a list of "Jobs" and when I tap one job I need to open that job and try to detail it more.. but I need to know how to go by index. Sorry my bad english hope u understand.. have a nice day

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:market_clean/screen/jobs/job_details.dart';
import 'package:market_clean/screen/welcomeScreen/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:market_clean/utills/color.dart';
import 'package:market_clean/utills/common_widget.dart';

class JobList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map> searchList;

  const JobList({
    Key? key,
    required this.searchList,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Get.to(JobDetails(searchList: workList));
      },
      child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: white,
            border: Border(
              right: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.grey.shade200),
              left: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.grey.shade200),
            ),
          ),
          child: ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: MyBehavior(),
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              itemCount: searchList.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      leading: Container(
                        height: 40,
                        width: 40,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(searchList[index]["image"]),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                      ),
                      title: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            searchList[index]["title"],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: black,
                                fontSize: 15,
                                fontFamily: "RobotoRegular"),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            searchList[index]["title"],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: gray95,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontFamily: "RobotoRegular"),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              text: searchList[index]["title"],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  fontFamily: "RobotoRegular",
                                  color: green),
                              children: const <TextSpan>[
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: ' in last one month',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      fontFamily: "RobotoRegular",
                                      color: gray95),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(220, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text(
                              searchList[index]["price"],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  color: blue,
                                  fontFamily: "RobotoBold"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Divider(
                      color: whiteF1,
                      thickness: 1,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my code and i want to get to another screen but only see the information of the one i selected (tapped)

Please, i would need some help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open any job detail when you tap that job, you should move Inkwell and onTap inside the ListView.builder and outside the ListTile.

And this way you can send index or anything of that item(job detail) to another screen.

Something like this :

```
class JobList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map> searchList;

  const JobList({
    Key? key,
    required this.searchList,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: white,
          border: Border(
            right: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.grey.shade200),
            left: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.grey.shade200),
          ),
        ),
        child: ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: MyBehavior(),
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            itemCount: searchList.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.to(JobDetails(jobIndex: index));
                    },
                    child: ListTile(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      leading: Container(
                        height: 40,
                        width: 40,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                            image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage(searchList[index]["image"]), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                      ),
                      title: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            searchList[index]["title"],
                            style: const TextStyle(color: black, fontSize: 15, fontFamily: "RobotoRegular"),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            searchList[index]["title"],
                            style: const TextStyle(color: gray95, fontSize: 12, fontFamily: "RobotoRegular"),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              text: searchList[index]["title"],
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontFamily: "RobotoRegular", color: green),
                              children: const <TextSpan>[
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: ' in last one month',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontFamily: "RobotoRegular", color: gray95),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(220, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text(
                              searchList[index]["price"],
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: blue, fontFamily: "RobotoBold"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    color: whiteF1,
                    thickness: 1,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much... I recently saw the answer and will try tomorrow. Thanks for the time I really apreciate it!